# Alexandru posted 2 duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I don't know how to edit them because they each have answers. I think [How is monetary policy sustainable, or even fair, in the current economy?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/5911) should be shortened?

Alexandru's question at [How is monetary policy sustainable, or even fair, in the current economy?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/5911), numbered

- 1 = [How is monetary policy fair in the current economy?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/5929).
- 2 =  [Who regulates the balancing of the books for commercial banks and how is this done? Is it public information?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/5930).

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand your question here. The two questions are not duplicates, though the asker draws from the same material, and even if they were, one of the questions are closed, so you would only need to deal with the second one.

If you are asking how to edit the first one so it can be re-opened, honestly I would say don't. Both of these questions are 5 years old, and the first one is a litany of many many questions that could each be a separate question. Trying to edit the first question to be re-openable would require really substantially changing the question from the original author's intent, so I'd say it's up to that user specifically to edit the question if they desire (I do not think they want to).

Comment: Alexandru asked the same question in three posts.